Issues with Action.Execute in Adaptive Card for Outlook: Not Hitting Endpoint
I'm trying to create an interactive Adaptive Card that I can send as JSON to Outlook. My goal is for users to press buttons on the card that will trigger requests to my API. Ideally, I'd like to provide feedback directly on the card, such as changing the button text or disabling it after submission.
I understand that I can use Action.Http, but I’m limited to version 1.1, which lacks some of the functionality I need. I've seen that Action.Execute is supposed to be a more advanced replacement for Action.Http, but I’m having trouble getting it to work.
The Issue:

Action.Execute Behavior: When I click the submit button on the card,
nothing happens. Instead, I receive an error message saying, "The
action could not be completed."
Provider Registration: I have registered the provider and included my
organization's originator ID in the Adaptive Card. I’ve also set the
target URL using a regex pattern like
https://.+\.exampleapi\.com/email_actions/.+, but nothing seems to be
hitting my endpoint.
Fallback Attempt: I also tried using version 1.4 with Action.Execute
and added a fallback to Action.Http, but that didn’t resolve the
issue either.

What I’ve Observed:

Browser Network Request: When I click the button, I notice that Outlook makes an internal request to https://outlook.office.com/actionsb2netcore/userid/messages/..., but this request doesn't seem to reach my specified endpoint. The request looks something like this:

JSON:
{
  "type":"invoke",
  "name":"adaptiveCard/action",
  "localTimezone":"",
  "localTimestamp":"",
  "value":{
    "action":{
      "type":"Action.Execute",
      "verb":"feedbackSubmission",
      "data":{
        "feedback":"some feedback"
      }
    },
    "trigger":"manual"
  },
  "from":{
    "id":"user@example.com"
  },
  "channelData":{
    "connectorSenderGuid":"some-guid",
    "adaptiveCardSignature":"some-signature"
  }
}

Questions:

Scope of Submission: Do I need to submit my provider under the
"Testing" scope for test users, or should I use the "Organization"
scope? Could this be affecting why my actions aren't triggering any
API requests?

Understanding the Request Flow: Can someone explain what happens
when the button is clicked in the context of Outlook? It seems like
the action is being intercepted internally by Outlook but isn't
reaching my backend.

Is there anything specific I should be doing to make Action.Execute
work properly in Outlook? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Do I Need an Azure Bot? Do Adaptive Cards in Outlook need to be processed by an
Azure Bot to handle user interactions? My goal is to send an email
with an Adaptive Card to a user and process the user's actions on
the backend by sending some requests. I have a feeling this might
require an Azure Bot, but I’m unsure how to trigger the bot to send
the Adaptive Card to the user, especially if the user didn't start a
conversation or perform any other action first.



I have a number of these up and running that are being sent using Logic Apps and I can walk you through what I've done since my use case is somewhat similar whereby it's an Outlook Actionable Message that is requiring a user response of either approve or reject.
When the either the approve/reject buttons are actioned, the card is updated so either of the buttons cannot be clicked again, but I'm not using Action.Execute to do this, Action.Http does what I need it to.
I've set up my scope of submission under the Organisation context with the URL of a Logic App that has a When a HTTP request has been received trigger. When the trigger has been actioned, the message is updated with a card that acknowledges receipt of the response and the buttons are removed.
Here's the JSON payload for sending the message.
​
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "autoInvokeAction": {
    "body": "{{JSON_BODY}}",
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "Authorization",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "application/json"
      }
    ],
    "method": "POST",
    "type": "Action.Http",
    "url": "{{URL_ENDPOINT}}"
  },
  "body": [
    {
      "id": "{{ANY_GUID}}",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "{{ANY_GUID}}",
          "text": "{{ANY_TEXT_HERE}}",
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "wrap": true
        },
        {
          "actions": [
            {
              "body": "{{JSON_BODY}}",
              "headers": [
                {
                  "name": "Authorization",
                  "value": ""
                },
                {
                  "name": "Content-Type",
                  "value": "application/json"
                }
              ],
              "id": "{{ANY_GUID}}",
              "method": "POST",
              "title": "Approve",
              "type": "Action.Http",
              "url": "{{URL_ENDPOINT}}"
            },
            {
              "card": {
                "body": [
                  {
                    "id": "Comments",
                    "isMultiline": true,
                    "isRequired": true,
                    "placeholder": "{{ANY_PLACEHOLDER_TEXT}}",
                    "type": "Input.Text"
                  },
                  {
                    "actions": [
                      {
                        "body": "{{JSON_BODY}}",
                        "headers": [
                          {
                            "name": "Authorization",
                            "value": ""
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json"
                          }
                        ],
                        "id": "{{ANY_GUID}}",
                        "method": "POST",
                        "title": "Submit",
                        "type": "Action.Http",
                        "url": "{{URL_ENDPOINT}}"
                      }
                    ],
                    "id": "{{ANY_GUID}}",
                    "type": "ActionSet"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "AdaptiveCard"
              },
              "id": "{{ANY_GUID}}",
              "title": "Reject",
              "type": "Action.ShowCard"
            }
          ],
          "id": "{{ANY_GUID}}",
          "type": "ActionSet"
        }
      ],
      "padding": "Default",
      "type": "Container"
    }
  ],
  "hideOriginalBody": true,
  "originator": "{{ORIGINATOR_GUID}}",
  "padding": "None",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0"
}

In the payload above, I have the autoInvoke action since for my purposes it's checking to see if the response has been received already by doing a database lookup and if it has, the message is updated before a button is clicked.
On the Logic App with a When a HTTP request has been received I have the payload configured to replicate the body of my approve and reject buttons. Following the HTTP trigger in my Logic App, I have the Response action set up as follows:

With the body of the Response action configured with the following JSON payload
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "body": [
    {
      "id": "{{ANY_GUID}}",
      "items": [
        {
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "id": "{{ANY_GUID}}",
          "size": "Medium",
          "text": "{{ANY_TEXT}}",
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "weight": "Bolder",
          "wrap": true
        }
      ],
      "padding": "Medium",
      "style": "emphasis",
      "type": "Container"
    },
    {
      "id": "{{ANY_GUID}}",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "{{ANY_GUID}}",
          "text": "{{ANY_TEXT}}",
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "wrap": true
        }
      ],
      "padding": "None",
      "type": "Container"
    }
  ],
  "hideOriginalBody": true,
  "padding": "None",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0"
} 

This will then update the message with this card so the approve/reject buttons can no longer be used.
I appreciate your API endpoints might be different, but this what I've been using and it's worked quite well.
Hope some of this might help!
